# Fetch all of the users post Facebook Graph Api

Tags: ajax, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

**JS**

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/"+uid+"/statuses?access_token="+atoken
    })
    .done(function( data ){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

the console logs

`Object {data: Array[0]}`

Why its showing no status when there are lots of statuses ?

But when uid of the **app developer account** is used its working well!

Why is this happeneing ?